# postgres docker : role "root" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running docker-compose in Github-Action. `docker-compose.yml` has following service definition for `postgres`

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./test/data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "pgdb"
      POSTGRES_USER: "pguser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "fr2Yitl4BgX"
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT:-5432}:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - "local-api"
```

But when container start on serf-hosted Github-Action runner, I see following

```
postgres    | 2021-12-02 19:48:33.537 UTC [414] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
postgres    | 2021-12-02 19:48:43.984 UTC [424] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
postgres    | 2021-12-02 19:48:54.265 UTC [433] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
postgres    | 2021-12-02 19:49:04.410 UTC [443] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

What is missing here ?

Comment: You showed us how you configured postgresql, but how did you configure GitHub runner?

Comment: I don't use Docker, but I am going to say the issue is:`test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]`. `pg_isready` without  `-U` is going to use the system user as the database user. Pretty sure in this case the system user where the command is running is `root`. `pg_isready` is `libpq` based so it will recognize  suitable `env` variables which for the user  is `PGUSER` per [libpq env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) not `POSTGRES_USER`.

Comment: How can I supply user for health check probe ?

Comment: I would try either `"pg_isready -U pguser"` or  add `PGUSER: pguser` to `environment` section. Like I said I'm not a Docker user, so this is educated guesses at best.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have tried setting up the env `PGUSER` and add `-U pguser` to the `pg_isready` command, it does not work.

Comment: If using `postgres` user add line `user: postgres` to database service and `pg_isready` command is enough.

Answer (score 49):

should set POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_USER in healthcheck

```sh
healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why this would be the case (why would you have to specify the credentials in the first place?)... but this is what solved it for me.

Comment: I was missing POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_USER, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a similar error when trying to run a pg_restore on the postgresql docker container, I had set up postgresql on docker-compose and was trying to restore a db (from my prev postgresql) to it. Just had the initial user as "postgres". Some errors I'd get:

1. pg_restore: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
2. createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

On research I found my pg_restore command needed to specify the User for it to work (tried specifying role, that failed)

Here's the working pg_restore command. Perhaps you can do similarly and find a way to specify user in yours?

```
#on docker container of psql, command that failed
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost --role=postgres -d thedbname /home/psql_backups/psql_myapp_220423.dumpbackup

#command that worked
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d thedbname /home/psql_backups/psql_myapp_220423.dumpbackup

# lastly (for those doing a pg_restore), from psql commandline, if the restore seems to have worked but don't see data, you may be on the wrong db
\c
\c theDbToSwitchTo
```

Comment: why you don't set -U postgres in docker container ?

Comment: ` initial user as "postgres"`this is postgres users ,not docker default user

Comment: I'll have to look into it, I use docker compose to set up my postgres container, and it isn't currently seeming to honor my initial POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD env vars